# Google cloud: invalid build: failed to check access to key

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Trying to create cloudbuild config for App Engine on Google cloud.
There are some encrypted environment variables that app needs. I did everything as [this](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/securing-builds/use-encrypted-secrets-credentials#encrypting_an_environment_variable_using_the_cryptokey) documentation says. When new Git commit has been pushed I'm always getting this error in cloudbuild log:

> invalid build: failed to check access to "projects/$PROJECT_ID/locations/global/keyRings/my-key-ring/cryptoKeys/my-key"

Also, there is one more question. If I execute `gcloud app deploy` command from my laptop app is being deployed and then fails to run because of absent environment variables. Is that correct that I need to define these variables along with command like

```
> MY_VAR1=a MY_VAR2=b gcloud app deploy
```

?
And if that's correct why it's not working?

Comment: Can you please provide exact command that produces this error? Also check necessary permissions as per documentation you provided. As for the second question [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#handlers_environment_variables) you can find how to provide env variables in app.yaml file.

Comment: First problem is a cloudbuild, it's triggered by push in dev branch. All permissions have been granted as documentation says. Second problem - just like in example, for example, there is STATIC_SECRET env variable that should be given to the app. If I run gcloud app deploy how am I supposed to set it? Because STATIC_SECRET=qwerty gcloud app deploy doesn't work. Sorry if that's weird question, docs cover simple use cases and it's completely unclear what to do with something complicated

Comment: Provide your env variables in `app.yaml` file following the link i posted before. Then just use `gcloud app deploy`, the env variables will automatically propagate to the instance and be accessible by the app. as for the first question can you please post your `cloudbuild.yaml` file as well as full error message. Don't forget to remove sensible information from them first.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is that the `$PROJECT_ID` variable is not supported in the `kmsKeyName` field. I had the same error and replacing `$PROJECT_ID` with my literal `project-name` was the fix.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56984975/771768 for a related problem.